# PDF does not load after goBack from webView

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, webview

I am currently displaying a pdf using a webView. In this pdf I have hyperlinks to other web sites.

The problem is that when I go to one of those web sites and scroll a little bit there, when I click the back button( that calls `webView.goBack()`) it goes back to the pdf, jumps to the top and can't scroll it anymore and can't see anything besides the first page so it might not load it right also.

Also, if I do the same, go to that website, but don't scroll there at all, or do anything at all. If I click the back button it takes me back to the pdf and works perfectly fine.

So any suggestions on what might go wrong here and how to fix it?

EDIT: I also added a image to show you how it looks

[image: pdf]

Comment: Do you have userInteraction and scrolling enabled for your webView?

Comment: Yes, I do have it enabled. It does work perfectly before tapping the hyperlink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I found for this is to reload the webView when the pdf is displayed again in the delegate method

When the navigation bar back button is tapped:

```
fileprivate var shouldReloadWebView: Bool = false

@objc private func tappedBackButton(_ button: UIButton) {
  if webView.canGoBack {
    shouldReloadWebView = true
    webView.goBack()
  } else {
    self.navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)
  }
}
```

In the delegate method:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
  if shouldReloadWebView {
    shouldReloadWebView = false
    webView.reload()
  }
}
```